# Errors after running eject on react application

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron, environment-variables, babeljs

I am building an electron app that utilizes react for the UI. I need to override the `webpack.config.js` file, and so I have ran the eject script, however I am now receiving the following error. There are limited resources regarding this issue so I am unsure what I can do to solve this.

> Using `babel-preset-react-app` requires that you specify `NODE_ENV` or
> `BABEL_ENV` environment variables. Valid values are "development",
> "test", and "production". Instead, received: undefined.

This error is appearing in every file, and is preventing it from compiling.

Comment: Have you tried to set those variables to one of the accepted values?

Comment: I have attempted to do so, but I am not sure which file they need to be declared in

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: Its a windows machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by adding the following lines to my eslintConfig within my package.json file.

```
"parser": "jsx",
"parserOptions": { "babelOptions": { "presets": [ ["babel-preset-react-app", false] ] } }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72250757/7259551